# How to pass a variable defined in C to Gnuplot through a pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, ubuntu-12.04, gnuplot

I need to pass a variable defined in my main program (plain C) to Gnuplot through a pipe. How can I do so? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

PS: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, GCC 4.6.3

The code:

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
    //fprintf(pipe, "bin_width = binsize; ");
    fprintf(pipe, "load 'Q3.gnu' \n");
    close(pipe);
```

EDIT: I have solved my own problem, sorry to take your time. The solution is:

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
    fprintf(pipe, "binsize = %f;", (float)binsize);
    fprintf(pipe, "load 'Q3.gnu' \n");
    close(pipe); 
    return 0;
```

Comment: Show your code. How does your C program communicate with `gnuplot`? What do you mean by passing a variable? Are you using `popen` ? How??

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am writing the part of the code relevant to my argument.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The variable binsize is defined in my source C code and I want to pass it to Gnuplot and use it for plotting purposes. I commented out that part since it ran into problems, also I would opt for directly making it usable by Gnuplot without renaming it if possible.

Comment: If you mean shell pipe `|` then just print to stdout what you want to feed to gnuplot. Otherwise, clarify the question.

Comment: @hyde Please have a look at my edited post, I am using piping inside my C source file as I indicated. If the user changes the binsize defined at the start of the code this should be passes to Gnuplot.

Comment: I see no variable (other than the `FILE*`) in the code you added. But gnuplot reads text. Just `fprintf` the text you want to give to gnuplot. What's the problem?

Comment: @hyde Did not think of that, sounds logical well I will give it a try. I meant modifying the file Q3.gnu beforehand, but is it possible to pass it directly?

Comment: Not sure what `load` does, but if it is essentially same as including contents of the file, then just do that in your C program (with modifications as needed) instead of using `load`. Or write a temp file and `load` that, whatever fits.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you an exact response, but gnuplot_i interface uses a pipe mechanism to comunicate with a gnuplot session. It seems very close to your request. I believe you can find useful information in the home page of the project (http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/).

Comment: Well thanks for your interest, I will have a look at the link you mentioned.